# In Laravel, should we use Event to reduce controller dependency?

Tags: php, events, dependency-injection, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say we are to implement a Facebook `Like` button, in backend a number of things may happen with this simple action. For example: `crawl page`, `extract page data`, `store page info`, `associate with user` etc...

After creating modules (libraries + repositories) for each steps, we need to put them together in controller. Would it be better to create controllers for each module, than injecting all of them within a single controller?

To illustrate in code, **is A more maintainable than B**?

**A:**

```
controllers/
  like.php
  crawler.php
  extract.php
  ...

//and in like.php
$page = Event::fire('page.crawler', $url);
...
$result = Event::fire('page.extract', $data);
...

//in crawler.php
use Lib/CrawlInterface;
function __construct (CrawlInterface $crawl)

//in extract.php
use Lib/ExtractInterface;
function __construct (ExtractInterface $extract)

...
```

**B:**

```
controllers/
  like.php

//and in like.php
use Lib/CrawlInterface;
use Lib/ExtractInterface;
use ...

function __construct (CrawlInterface $crawl, ExtractInterface $extract, ...)
```

Obviously this is not a black & white question, but I would like to know whether `Event` should be used this way, as it seems like a good way for reducing the number of DI on each controller (also prevent controller from going fat.)

Answer (score 1):

Controllers in Laravel are meant to provide endpoints into your webapp with some basic functionality.  You should not be communicating between two controllers - abstract out your code into separate classes that controllers can simply invoke.  This way your controllers stay separated and focused on what their respective routes are meant to do, but can still call the complex domain level functionality you want without mucking up communication.

Comment: Thank you for the endpoint mention into exclusive controllers. I would have liked to hear something about events though